# Hyperlink + Javascript = One click?

Tags: javascript, html, sharepoint, hyperlink

Is it possible to integrate a javascript into a hyperlink? Or make it into some sort of batch script or whatnot, so when the page has loaded it calls the javascript which is a button on the page?

To explain it further:

We have this page:
http://work.acceptance.XXXX.com/XXXX_Raffle/Lists/Raffle/overview.aspx

The sharepoint page has a survey on it.
To get the "popup" window to show, so you can answer a question in the survey, you need to press a button which calls this script:

```
javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$m$g_e999ab40_719f_42fb_bd61_d986f232bdd5$ctl01$ctl00$toolBarTbl$RptControls$ctl00$diidIONewItem','');
```

So, is it possible to somehow combine the page + the javascript, so all they have to do is press one link or alternatively, a hyperlink which goes to a file on a server which triggers all this, so they instantly get to the page + the javascript automatically pops so they dont have to press the button?

Keep in mind, when I say "hyperlink" I mean the kind of hyperlink you would see in an email. A simple link to a website or a server location.

I'm not very good at everything that has to do with programming and webdesign, but I do have access to the sharepoint, though I'd need serious guiding in how to add anything there other than simple webparts. It's SharePoint Server 2010.

Here is a picture of the button and what happens when you press it.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/gKCG5.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an onload event to the page to get it to show the popup:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = showPopup();

    function showPopup() {
        __doPostBack('ctl00$m$g_e999ab40_719f_42fb_bd61_d986f232bdd5$ctl01$ctl00$toolBarTbl$RptControls$ctl00$diidIONewItem','');
    }
</script>
```

This needs to go on the page that you're linking to so that the link takes you to this page which then fires this onload. Put it before the closing  tag on the page.

Comment: Hey, seems nice. But where do I add this? Straight into the code on the page?

Comment: It needs adding in <script> tags in the <head> section of the page. I'll edit the answer to show you.

Comment: Hmpf, when editing the overview.aspx in Sharepoint Designer Advanced Mode, I can't see the all the other <script> tags which are visible if I just rightclick and do "View Source" in IE.
If I just add it at the end of the visible code, it gives the entire page an error when trying to load it, i.e. "Parser Error" and complains about the <script type="text/javascript"> line.

Comment: Do you know if jQuery is being used on your site? If so, this code can be changed to load on DOM ready and can be added anywhere on the page - albeit that isn't best practice but it might be a solution for you here. Try this [link](http://blog.cloudshare.com/2012/10/29/how-to-insert-custom-javascript-code-in-sharepoint-2013-pages-part-i/)

Comment: Yeah.. nah, I can't make this happen. Nothing works. Thanks though, this is most likely the answer if I had a bit more knowledge with HTML.

Answer (score 0):

No. You cannot construct a URL that will load a document and then call some JavaScript.

You would have to modify the page you are linking to so it runs the JS automatically. It could look at the URL and run that function conditionally though (e.g. `if (location.hash === '#foo') { ... }`.)

Comment: Ah, alright.
Thought I have no idea what you mean by the below.
I guess that's way above my skill.